# Alternative to Wireshark for raw Ethernet capture over USB-Ethernet adapter

Tags: sockets, usb, ethernet, wireshark

(Apologies: I uninstalled and reinstalled WinPcap and now I can see the extra interface! Suggestion found in Wireshark FAQ. I leave the original question below.)

I use WireShark to examine ethernet packet contents at the byte level (in/out of custom FPGA-based hardware).  I have a USB-Ethernet adapter to add a second Ethernet port to my laptop. It was a cheap Chinese device bought on Ebay but now that I've found an appropriate driver, it works OK. However, I see that, on Windows, WinPcap/WireShark [doesn't support Ethernet capture over USB](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB).

While it would be nice if WireShark could be made to work on USB capture, I'm really looking for an alternative way to grab the raw ethernet bytes. I have some perl scripts set up that operate on the raw frames output from tshark, (Wireshark command line) and I could easily feed it from any stream of frames/bytes.

Is anyone doing something similar or is there a tidy way to output the raw bytes?

Sniffed raw USB bytes would be OK, but it would be nicer if someone has already programmed/scripted extracting the Ethernet frames. I'm using perl but any compiled app or python or C# or C++ or .. would be fine.

Comment: AFAIK there is no USB packet capture module for Wireshark at the Windows platform.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm trying to workaround - I don't need Wireshark, but I need access to the raw packet.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned python, scapy can do a LOT of raw packet things, might want to look at that. From their git:

> Scapy is a powerful Python-based interactive packet manipulation
>   program and library.
>
> It is able to forge or decode packets of a wide number of protocols,
>   send them on the wire, capture them, store or read them using pcap
>   files, match requests and replies, and much more. It is designed to
>   allow fast packet prototyping by using default values that work.
>
> It can easily handle most classical tasks like scanning, tracerouting,
>   probing, unit tests, attacks or network discovery (it can replace
>   hping, 85% of nmap, arpspoof, arp-sk, arping, tcpdump, wireshark, p0f,
>   etc.). It also performs very well at a lot of other specific tasks
>   that most other tools can't handle, like sending invalid frames,
>   injecting your own 802.11 frames, combining techniques (VLAN
>   hopping+ARP cache poisoning, VoIP decoding on WEP protected channel,
>   ...), etc.
>
> Scapy supports Python 2.7 and Python 3 (3.3 to 3.6). It's intended to
>   be cross platform, and runs on many different platforms (Linux, OSX,
>   *BSD, and Windows).

Check them out at https://github.com/secdev/scapy

Comment: Good to know about, but Scapy needs to sit on top of Npcap or WinPcap which was where my issue was. (I misunderstood my problem initially, thinking I would need to manipulate raw USB traffic. Reinstalling WinPcap was enough to update the list of available interfaces, so I didn't.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Windows PC readily at hand to test, but as far as I can tell, there is *no* problem capturing Ethernet frames in Wireshark on Windows, from a USB-Ethernet adapter.

To clarify, just select the USB-Ethernet device as you would any other, and you are set.

̶W̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶d̶o̶,̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶c̶a̶p̶t̶u̶r̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶U̶S̶B̶ ̶b̶u̶s̶ ̶t̶r̶a̶f̶f̶i̶c̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶w̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶w̶a̶n̶t̶e̶d̶,̶ ̶r̶i̶g̶h̶t̶?̶

Edit from the far future: Wireshark can now also capture USB traffic, not only Ethernet traffic.

Comment: The USB Ethernet device doesn't appear as an interface to select in Wireshark. tshark.exe -D reports only 2 interfaces: my "real" Ethernet connection and the wireless LAN, but that's it. ipconfig lists all 3.